# Copying built OpenCV from one Docker image to another

Tags: docker, opencv, dockerfile

Using [this `Dockerfile`](https://github.com/loitho/docker-opencv-cuda) with just the important parts highlighted for simplicity:

```
RUN cd /opencv-$OPENCV_VERSION/cmake_binary \
    && cmake -DBUILD_TIFF=ON \
    && make install

## Compress the openCV files so you can extract them from the docker easily 
RUN tar cvzf opencv-$OPENCV_VERSION.tar.gz --directory=$OPENCV_INSTALL_PATH .
```

Now, I want to build my application in a new container, so as far as I understand the documentation I can go:

```
FROM docker-opencv-cuda:cv3.3.1_cuda8 AS opencv

COPY -from=opencv /opencv/ /opencv/
```

However, I get an error:

> invalid from flag value opencv: pull access denied for opencv, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'

Looking around, it seems that `COPY -from` is trying to reference either a private or public repository, but I'd like it to look for my local version as `docker image ls` reports:

```
REPOSITORY           TAG             IMAGE ID
docker-opencv-cuda   cv3.3.1_cuda8   xxxx
docker-opencv-cuda   cv3.3.1_cuda9   yyyy
```

How can I do what I want to do? Adding to a repository is not a valid option as later I will have proprietary code that I cannot share, etc.

**UPDATE**: I might have found a bug? I have Docker 18.09.0, and given the lines:

```
ARG CV_VERSION=cv3.3.1_cuda8
FROM docker-opencv-cuda:$CV_VERSION AS opencv

COPY -from=opencv /opencv/ /opencv/
COPY -from=docker-opencv-cuda:$CV_VERSION /opencv/ /opencv/
COPY -from=docker-opencv-cuda:cv3.3.1_cuda8 /opencv/ /opencv/
```

Only the third `COPY` with the full `-from` label works.

**UPDATE 2**: Docker newbie problem. My `Dockerfile` is incorrect as `-from` should not refer to the current `FROM`, so this is OK and does what I want:

```
ARG CV_VERSION=cv3.3.1_cuda8
FROM docker-opencv-cuda:$CV_VERSION AS opencv

# Switch context so the OpenCV files no longer exist in the current image
FROM another_package

COPY -from=opencv /opencv/ /opencv/
COPY -from=docker-opencv-cuda:$CV_VERSION /opencv/ /opencv/
COPY -from=docker-opencv-cuda:cv3.3.1_cuda8 /opencv/ /opencv/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First map your local disk when start docker and copy data from docker into the local disk.

such as:

```
$ docker run --it -rm -v /your_path:/your_path  your_image
# cp -rf /opencv /your_path 
# exit
```

Then create your new docker, and copy the data from the local.

Comment: I was thinking about that as a workaround and I might just adopt that since as I note in my update `COPY -from` looks dodgy.